# Laravel 1048 Column cannot be NULL

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to save a new interviewTrack I'm getting 1048 Column 'status' cannot be NULL. I've fill all the field, and when I dd it shows all data that I fill

here's the result when I dd it :

```
"driver_id" => "82"
"interviewTracks" => array:1 [▼
0 => array:5 [▼
  "id" => ""
  "track_date" => "2016-11-11"
  "status" => "2"
  "outcome" => "1"
  "remark" => "ggg"
```

here's my save code so far :

```
public function saveHandler(Request $request, $obj)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $obj->fill($request->all());
        if (!$obj->save()) {
            throw new ValidationException($obj->errors());
        }
            foreach($request->interviewTracks as $interviewTracks) {
                if (empty($interviewTracks['id'])) {
                    $interviewTracks = new InterviewTrack();
                }
                else {
                    $interviewTracks = InterviewTrack::find($interviewTracks['id']);
                }
                $interviewTracks->interview()->associate($obj);
                $interviewTracks['interview_id'] = isset($interviewTracks['interview_id']);
                $interviewTracks->status = $interviewTracks['status'];
                $interviewTracks->track_date = $interviewTracks['track_date']; 
                $interviewTracks->outcome = $interviewTracks['outcome'];
                $interviewTracks->remarks = $interviewTracks['remarks'];
                $interviewTracks->save();
            };
            if (!$interviewTracks->save()) {
                throw new ValidationException($interviewTracks->errors());
            }

        DB::commit();
        return $this->sendSuccessResponse($request);
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->errors);
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request, $e->errors);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return $this->sendErrorResponse($request,'Unable to process. Please contact system Administrator');
    }

}
```

any idea ?

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `dd` statement?

Comment: @linuxartisan it's working now, but im getting another error. Undefined index: remarks.

Comment: That's because you have `remark` field, not `remarks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting

> Undefined index remarks error

is that you don't have `remarks` field.

Change this line

`$interviewTracks->remarks = $interviewTracks['remarks'];`

to this

`$interviewTracks->remarks = $interviewTracks['remark'];`

Comment: I do have remarks field in database, and it's using 's' at the end.